# Flutter run errors on android Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method)

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

My code working fine on iOS. But android i take some errors. How can i solve it? Application is working fine on ios. but when i try run on android i see that errors on debug console
My flutter version is 1.22
And flutter doctor give any error.
i try flutter clean and removing old version from device. but stil same error

Here is error list:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on channel
plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configure on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)
```

my pubspec.yaml

```
name: doctorfinder_new
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl:
  intl_translation:
    
  google_fonts: ^1.1.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+1
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  geolocator: ^6.2.1
  toast: ^0.1.5
  masked_text_input_formatter: "0.0.1"
  http: ^0.12.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  email_validator: ^1.0.6
  loadmore: ^1.0.4
  paging: ^0.1.0
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/homeScreenImages/
    - assets/moreScreenImages/
    - assets/loginScreenImages/
    - assets/detailScreenImages/
    - assets/specialityScreenImages/
    - assets/makeAppointmentScreenImages/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.doctorfinder_new">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="doctorfinder_new"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally my Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.doctorfinder_new;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
```

Here is my GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
import com.roughike.facebooklogin.facebooklogin.FacebookLoginPlugin;
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin;
import com.aloisdeniel.geocoder.GeocoderPlugin;
import com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapsPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin;
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 */
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
    FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin"));
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    FacebookLoginPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.roughike.facebooklogin.facebooklogin.FacebookLoginPlugin"));
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
    FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin"));
    GeocoderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.aloisdeniel.geocoder.GeocoderPlugin"));
    GeolocatorPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.baseflow.geolocator.GeolocatorPlugin"));
    GoogleMapsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapsPlugin"));
    GoogleSignInPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin"));
    ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"));
    PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"));
    SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
    SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));
    UrlLauncherPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin"));
  }

  private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = GeneratedPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you installed a new plugin uninstall the app from the device and run it again.

Comment: no. not about new plugin install. i try flutter clean , and remove from device. but same error

Comment: when application run. Application resume runing but i cant use this methods